# migrate from tastypie to DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, tastypie

I'm working on django-tastypie project and I want to migrate to django rest framework.
I need an article or a document or anything else that help me to this.
for example [this document](https://github.com/refinery-platform/refinery-platform/issues/491) bring a sample of both framework and evaluate them.
I want to answer to question like:
what's different between 'Serializer' in tastypie and DRF?
what's equivalent of tastypie resource class in DRF?
and so on...
I search all of the same document but I don't find helpful doc!